# convert a array to xml

Tags: php

I want to convert a php array to xml.

I have this code:

```
$output=array("result" => "this is the result");

print assocArrayToXML("example",$output);


function assocArrayToXML($root_element_name,$ar) {

     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><{$root_element_name}></{$root_element_name}>");

     $f = create_function('$f,$c,$a','
        foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
                   if(is_array($v)) {
            $ch=$c->addChild($k);
            $f($f,$ch,$v);
        } else {
            $c->addChild($k,$v);
        }
    }');
    $f($f,$xml,$ar);
    return $xml->asXML();
    }
```

I found the function here:

http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php

When I execute the code, I got this:

```
this is the result
```

Why can't I see the xml? is it because it is malformed? or maybe the mozilla firefox doesn't write it?

Comment: PHP has closures now, no need for nasty eval `create_function` stuff.

Comment: Did you look at the source code or just the output in the browser?

Comment: AS to why you can't see it; you're looking at it in a web browser.... do a "view source"

Comment: yes! this workede Mark Baker, if you put it as answer I will mark it as the solution

Comment: I think @str said the same thing about 10 seconds before me